# Word Mail Merging saving as individual files

Tags: c#, performance

I've been working on making word's mail merge automatic in C# using Interop Services. It works, but for generating 47 files it takes 2-3 minutes, any way I can make it faster?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Vizsgalatok_elkeszitese
{
   class MergeMultiple
   {
    private string wordDocumentPath;
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains key value pairs for the Word document's merge fields. The keys are the field's name and the values are the data you want to insert, it should contain a key-value pair for the FileNames
    /// </summary>
    private List<Dictionary<string, string>> MergeFields;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="WordDocumentPath">Path to the Word Document</param>
    /// <param name="MergeFields"></param>
    public MergeMultiple(string WordDocumentPath, List<Dictionary<string,string>> MergeFields)
    {
        wordDocumentPath = WordDocumentPath;
        this.MergeFields = MergeFields;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performes the merge and saves the files with the given Format
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="DestinationFolder"></param>
    /// <param name=""></param>
    public void Merge(string DestinationFolder, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat Format, string FileNameKey, bool CreateFolder=true)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApplication = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDocument = null;

        bool FileNameKeyExists = false;
        foreach (Dictionary<string,string> FieldValuePair in MergeFields)
        {
            if(FieldValuePair.ContainsKey(FileNameKey))
            {
                FileNameKeyExists = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!FileNameKeyExists) throw new ArgumentException("The given key for FileName doesn't exist");

        if(!Directory.Exists(DestinationFolder))
        {
            if (!CreateFolder) throw new IOException("Destination folder doesn't exist");
            else Directory.CreateDirectory(DestinationFolder);
        }
        try
        {
            wordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            foreach (Dictionary<string, string> FieldValuePair in MergeFields)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document MergeDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Add(wordDocumentPath);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Fields DocumentFields= MergeDocument.Fields;
                //Search through fields and replace any Mergefield found
                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field Field in DocumentFields)
                {
                    string FieldText = Field.Code.Text;
                    if (FieldText.StartsWith(" MERGEFIELD"))
                    {
                        string FieldName = FieldText.Substring(11, FieldText.Length - 11).Trim();
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> Entry in FieldValuePair)
                        {
                            if (Entry.Key.Equals(FieldName,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                            {
                                Field.Select();
                                wordApplication.Selection.TypeText(Entry.Value);                                    
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(DocumentFields);

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Sections DocumentSections= MergeDocument.Sections;
                //Search through the headers and footers for Mergefields and replace it
                foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section Section in DocumentSections)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Fields HeaderFields = Section.Headers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.Fields;
                    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field Field in HeaderFields)
                    {
                        string FieldText = Field.Code.Text;
                        if (FieldText.StartsWith(" MERGEFIELD"))
                        {
                            string FieldName = FieldText.Substring(11, FieldText.Length - 11).Trim();
                            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> Entry in FieldValuePair)
                            {
                                if (Entry.Key.Equals(FieldName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                                {
                                    Field.Select();
                                    wordApplication.Selection.TypeText(Entry.Value);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(HeaderFields);
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(DocumentSections);
                MergeDocument.SaveAs2(Path.Combine(DestinationFolder, FieldValuePair[FileNameKey]), Format);
                MergeDocument.Close(false);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(MergeDocument);
            }

        }
        ///TODO
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {                
            wordApplication.Quit(false);                
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApplication);
        }
    }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Private fields, local variables and method's parameters should be *camelCased*:

```
private List<Dictionary<string, string>> mergeFields;

public MergeMultiple(string wordDocumentPath, List<Dictionary<string,string>> mergeFields)

bool fileNameKeyExists = false;
```

Also `mergeFields` field should be readonly:

```
private readonly List<Dictionary<string, string>> mergeFields;
```

I recommend also to use different naming for private fields, for example, `_mergeFields`. It helps to easily distinguish fields from parameters and local variables.

---

Use `var` keyword for long types like `Dictionary<string,string>`:

```
foreach (var fieldValuePair in _mergeFields)

foreach (var field in documentFields)

var documentSections = MergeDocument.Sections;
```

---

This code

> ```
> bool FileNameKeyExists = false;
> foreach (Dictionary<string,string> FieldValuePair in MergeFields)
> {
>     if(FieldValuePair.ContainsKey(FileNameKey))
>     {
>         FileNameKeyExists = true;
>         break;
>     }
> }
> ```

can be rewritten as

```
var fileNameKeyExists = _mergeFields.Any(f => f.ContainsKey(FileNameKey));
```

---

You should release COM objects in `finally` block to ensure that references are released even if an exception is occured. For example:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Fields headerFields = null;

try
{
    headerFields = Section.Headers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.Fields;

    // ...
}
finally
{
    if (headerFields != null)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(headerFields);
}
```

---

You have a lot of inner loops so I suggest to split your code into small methods decreasing nesting level of your code and increasing its readability.